# What is the max value of integer in dart?

Tags: dart

I have looked everywhere but I couldnt find any information related to this topic. 
Also, Is there a java - like Long / BigDecimal datatype in dart?

Comment: Have a look at [Built in Types](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch02.html#built-in-types)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Dart 2**

For dart2js generated JavaScript, Pixel Elephant's answer is still true.

> within the range -2<sup>53</sup> to 2<sup>53</sup>

Other execution platforms have fixed-size integers with 64 bits.

The type `BigInt` was added to `typed_data`

> Since Dart 2.0 will switch to fixed-size integers, we also added a `BigInt` class to the `typed_data` library. Developers targeting dart2js can use this class as well. The `BigInt` class is *not* implementing num, and is completely independent of the num hierarchy.

**Dart 1**

There are also the packages

- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/bignum
- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/decimal

Comment: So beginning with Dart 2.0, is the range of `int` for Android and iOS same which is `-2^63 to 2^63 - 1`

Answer (score 15):

That depends if you are running in the Dart VM or compiling to JavaScript.

On the Dart VM an `int` is arbitrary precision and has no limit.

When compiling to JavaScript you are actually using floating point numbers, since that is all that JavaScript supports. This means you are restricted to representing integers within the range -2<sup>53</sup> to 2<sup>53</sup>

Comment: Thanks! That was quite helpful!

Comment: What do you mean by arbitrary precision? Like a bignum? The documentation says it's 64 bit on Dart VM

Comment: Has no limit? how is that possible?

Comment: It technically does have a limit, which is the size of your computer's memory. @DanielGomezRico

Comment: @wdavies973 Do you have any docs that explain that a little bit? Im totally shocked about this, all languages I saw have a defined representation of the biggest thing they can hold.

Comment: So here's a basic explanation: yes, most languages do have a defined limit. This will typically match the underlying hardware - commonly either 32-bit or 64-bit. Some languages however will implement numbers with arbitrary precision for flexibility's sake (see Python). Arbitrary precision takes some special coding, because your computer can only do arithmetic only at most 64-bit numbers, so when a language uses arbitrary precision, they're typically using a special implementation that eventually breaks arithmetic down into smaller 64-bit chunks. @DanielGomezRico

Comment: @DanielGomezRico Read more: https://rushter.com/blog/python-integer-implementation/#:~:text=Python%20represents%20all%20objects%20by%20C%20structures.&text=Generally%2C%20In%20languages%20like%20C,are%20represented%20as%20a%20bignum. Its also important to note that arbitrary precision numbers are a bit slower than using the native.

Comment: This is no longer true - see the other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31691112/2215742

Comment: In modern Dart the integers are not arbitrary precision any more.  See more about this decision here: https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/g/core-dev/c/ZdEBRgxLb70/m/a-s-iS6JAAAJ

Answer (score 3):

First option:

```
int maxInteger = double.maxFinite.toInt();
```

Better way:

```
const maxInteger = -1 >>> 1;
```

The >>> right shift with zero padding

will transform 1111 ... 1111 (-1 representation) to 0111 ... 1111 (max int representation)

```
const minInteger = -maxInteger;
```