# How to get the maxium value of an Integer in dart?

Tags: dart

In java we can just `Integer.maxValue` but dart there is not this method.

I am using `int max = 1<<32` but this doesn't work properly when compiling to javascript.

What is the best way to get the integer maximum value using dart language?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the max value of integer in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31687376/what-is-the-max-value-of-integer-in-dart)

Comment: THis is not a duplicate since it does not have the code, only the theory.

Comment: I don't understand; the question is a duplicate.  Do you mean you don't know how to translate theory into code?  Also, the answer is that there is *no* cross-platform way to get the maximum integer value.

Comment: The question is not the same. The first one asked the maxium size, my question asks of HOW to achieve it. But the answer for my question is "there is no way", so, there is'nt much I can do.

Comment: I think the distinction is subtle enough to not matter.  Or perhaps instead: [Is there a constant for max/min int/double value in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50429660/is-there-a-constant-for-max-min-int-double-value-in-dart)

Comment: Also, if the maximum is important, then perhaps consider instead using the [fixnum package](https://pub.dev/packages/fixnum) and using `Int64` (or `Int32`) instead of `int`.

Comment: Thank you man, I will take a look on it! Best regards!

Answer (score 3):

I was using [dart_numerics](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_numerics) package in my app for another reason and found it while typing

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```dart
double.maxFinite.toInt() // e.g. 9223372036854775807 on x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no method because the int maximum values are fixed.
According to the documentation:

> Integers While the language specifies an arbitrarily sized integer,
>   for performance reasons the VM has three different internal integer
>   representations: smi (rhymes with pie), mint, and bigint. Each
>   representation is used to hold different ranges of integer numbers
>   (see the table). The VM automatically switches between these
>   representations behind the scenes as numbers grow and shrink in range.

You can read about that here: https://dart.dev/articles/archive/numeric-computation

Comment: The maximum value isn't really fixed, and the answer depends on whether Dart is compiled for the VM/runtime or for JavaScript.  In the latter case, `int`s are represented as floating-point numbers, so the "maximum" is vague.  See https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-core/int-class.html